# Where should I handle a variable using MVC methodology?

Tags: php, templates

F.e. I get a variable and an MVC application has to show slightly different JS depending on the variable. Where should I handle this variable into View or Controller?
What does MVC methodology say?

$max_orders_count may be > 0 or = 0 if its Infinite.

**First way**

```
Controller:

if ($max_orders_count === 0) {
$this->view('view1.php');
} elseif ($max_orders_count > 0) {
$this->view('view2.php');
}
```

**Second way**

```
Controller:

$this->view('view.php', array('max_orders_count' => $max_orders_count));

View:

<?if ($max_orders_count === 0) {?>
     <script>JS1</script>
<?}?>

<?if ($max_orders_count > 0) {?>
     <script>JS2</script>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Give a more detailed example please

Comment: "Handle"? Handle in what way? Are you really using MVC, most web frameworks that claim MVC aren't, and are instead using model/view/template, which is often called MVC, but is in fact nothing like MVC at all. What framework *are* you using?

Comment: jim, I did.

Mr. Regebro what is the difference between MVC and MTC (template)?

Comment: @user1312750 They are basically completely different. What framework are you using?

Comment: Some more explanations: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html#the-mtv-or-mvc-development-pattern

Comment: @LennartRegebro I'm using Code Igniter.
Thank you for the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses the typical web patten of an optional model, and a HTML template with code in it (a PHP page, since it's PHP) and a class that talks between the template and the model.

CodeIgniter calls the PHP file a "view" (some frameworks, especially outside PHP, call it a template) and it calls the intermediary class a "controller" (some frameworks calls it a "view").

That means that the pattern CodeIgniter calls MVC has very little to do with traditional MVC frameworks, which are event-driven and used mostly for GUI application.

This also means that the answer to your question is: **You can handle the variable wherever you like!**

It is generally frowned upon having code in the template. Anything complex code-wise should co in thew controller. But this is just doing a conditional check, and that can go in the template.